# Shopify Ruby Script Error - discount code requirements not met (empty cart)

Tags: ruby, shopify

I am working on a script that would block promo code usage for products that are tagged with 'sale' - I am seeing an error message on line 1 of my script and I'm not sure how to resolve it. The script otherwise functions fine and works as expected.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this error?

```
# ================================ Customizable Settings ================================
# ================================================================
# Define the tag for products where discounts are not allowed.
# ================================================================
SALE_TAGS = ['sale', 'Sale'] # Tags used to identify sale products
REJECTION_MESSAGE = "Discount codes can't be used with Sale products"

# ================================ Script Code (do not edit) ================================
# ================================================================
# ProductSelector
# Finds matching products by the entered criteria.
# ================================================================
class ProductSelector
  def initialize(tags)
    @tags = tags.map(&:downcase)
  end

  def match?(line_item)
    product_tags = line_item.variant.product.tags.map(&:downcase)
    (@tags & product_tags).any?
  end
end

# ================================================================
# DisableDiscountCodesForProductsCampaign
# If any matching items are in the cart, the discount code is rejected.
# ================================================================
class DisableDiscountCodesForProductsCampaign
  def initialize(tags, message)
    @product_selector = ProductSelector.new(tags)
    @rejection_message = message
  end

  def run(cart)
    return if cart.discount_code.nil?

    if cart.line_items.any? { |line_item| @product_selector.match?(line_item) }
      cart.discount_code.reject(message: @rejection_message)
    end
  end
end

# ================================================================
# Campaign Execution
# ================================================================
campaign = DisableDiscountCodesForProductsCampaign.new(SALE_TAGS, REJECTION_MESSAGE)
campaign.run(Input.cart)
Output.cart = Input.cart
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also encountered this issue. I resolved it by removing the code I was testing with from the cart input.

Once you remove the discount code, make a small change in the code editor (adding an extra space for example) to trigger the error checker again. It should now be resolved.